# Navigating to a page from a page WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a window(MainWindow.xaml) and 2 pages(page1.xaml,page2.xaml).In Page1, i have a button.

Now, i can use this :

```
  Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
  Frame.navigate(new page2)
  End sub
```

What i want is, i want to navigate to page2 by clicking the button on page1..

Something like this :

```
 'This code is in Page1

  Private sub Btn1_Click handles btn.click
  MainWIndows.Frame.Navigate(new page2)
  End sub
```

This code doesn't work...One solution i found was to create a frame in page1 first and then navigate to page2 within the frame of page1 whereas i want to use the frame of MainWindow...Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God darn it! It was damn easy..In page1 , i added:

```
Me.Navigationservice.Navigate(new page2)
```